# Postgre SQL - Need one of multiple conditions to be true within a set of conditions (where clause has multiple other sets)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am attempting to write a query involving needing to see if a given value is in at least 1 of a given set of columns. Normally, I'd use an OR clause for this, but in this case, I have other conditions that MUST be met, and a set of conditions that at least 1 need to be true.

For context, this is involving finding if a teacher is the main teacher OR a co-teacher in a table. They can be either, but I need to check 6 total columns for this (main_teacher_id and co_teacher_id1-5)

But I have other conditions that must be true, like the course must be from the 2023 school year and course_id can't be in a given set of other values.

Is it possible to group Where clauses and only return if one of those is met?

Comment: Use parentheses.

Comment: You can also avoid the use of `or` by constructing it this way: `where colA = X and Y in (main_teacher_id, co_teacher_id1, co_teacher_id2, co_teacher_id3, co_teacher_id4, co_teacher_id5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question right, but what about a `WHERE` clause like this:

```
WHERE EXTRACT (year FROM course_date) = 2023
  AND course_id NOT IN (1, 2, 3)
  AND (main_teacher_id = 42 OR
       co_teacher_id1 = 42 OR
       co_teacher_id2 = 42 OR
       co_teacher_id3 = 42 OR
       co_teacher_id4 = 42 OR
       co_teacher_id5 = 42)
```